# How to open cash drawer on ionic using BluetoothSerial

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Please help me, how to open cash drawer on ionic using BluetoothSerial, because my printer cannot detect if using StarPRNT plugin.
This code using BluetoothSerial can work for print.

```
 printDocument() {
      var data = "Hello";
      this.bluetoothSerial.write(data).then(() => {}, () => {});
 }
```

But if i using StarPRNT library my device cannot detect.

```
 cariPrinterStar() {
      this.starprnt.portDiscovery('Bluetooth')
      .then((res: any) => {
           let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                title     : "Msg",
                subTitle  : JSON.stringify(res),
                buttons   : ["OK"]
           });
           alert.present();
      })
      .catch((error: any) => {
           console.error(error)
      });
 }
```

Comment: Hi, without any more information, or specifics with which you have problems, it's impossible to answer your question. Please share a minimal example of what you have, and we might be able to help.

Comment: thank you erik, i was revision my question

Comment: So, what's the error?

Comment: i have no error erik, but on https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial ,not provide API for open cash drawer, can you give me recomendation how to open cash drawer on ionic 3?